# Blackberry - LabelField Dynamic Update Issues

Tags: blackberry

I am trying to develop a BlackBerry app for a Storm2. I am facing a problem when trying to update a LabelField from a different instance of the app.

The program is working fine without updating this LabelField, but when I tried to add the code to update the text, it becomes unresponsive after the "settext" line.

Am I missing something?

```
public class AgentTrackerScreen extends MainScreen
{
    public static LabelField _outputText;
    ...
}

public class BtService implements Runnable
{
    ...
    public void run() 
    {
        AgentTrackerScreen._outputtext.settext(
            "Something: " + btListener.vecDevices.size());
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Try splitting the code inside your `run()` method into two lines (first line creates the string and second line uses the string in `settext`) to see whether the problem is with `settext` or with `btListener.vecDevices.size()`.

Comment: I have already tried that. btListener.vecDevices.size() is working fine; I think settext is the one that have issues.

Answer (score 3):

You must make all user interface modifications on the event thread, or else lock the user interface before doing it. See [BlackBerry UI Threading Basics](http://thinkingblackberry.com/?p=182) for details.

(BTW, this is a common requirement in many user interface systems. Swing in Java SE has this requirement. So does WPF on Windows.)

Answer (score 1):

Use either:

- invokeAndWait(Runnable r)
- invokeLater(Runnable r)
- synchronize on UiApplication.getEventLock()